# Show that $V(x^2y^2+x^2-xy-y^2)$ is irreducible.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

This comes from the book Ideals, Varieties and Algorithms by Cox et al. It is not the exact question. But I need this fact to show that this variety is a rational variety. I think to be a rational variety, it has to be irreducible first.

> Show that $V=V(x^2y^2+x^2-xy-y^2)$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

I showed that the function $f(x,y)$ is irreducible by assuming $f=g\cdot h$ and eliminating all cases.

Now I need to show that $I(V)=\left\langle x^2y^2+x^2-xy+y^2\right\rangle$.

I used this method to show $V(y^5-x^2)$ is a rational variety. It is easy because it has a polynomial parametrization.

However this $V$ has only a rational parametrization
$$x=\frac{-t^2+t+1}{t^2+1}\\y=\frac{-t^2+t+1}{t(t+2)}$$

I don't think I can use this to show $I(V)=\left\langle x^2y^2+x^2-xy+y^2\right\rangle$.

Any help would be appreciated!

**Edit**:

There is a theorem in the book stating that if $V$ can be parameterized by polynomials or rational functions, then $V$ is irreducible. This solves the problem. It is in Chapter 4, section 5 of the book by Cox. et al.

Comment: It is sometimes possible to have $f(x, y)$ irreducible in $\mathbb{R}[x, y]$, and yet $V ( f(x, y) )$ to be reducible! For example, $f(x, y)= (x^2 - 1)^2 + y^2$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{R}[x, y]$, but $V( f(x, y) ) $ consists of two points $(-1, 0)$ and $(1, 0)$, so is reducible. So there is something more to show! +1

Comment: @Prism: Thank you for pointing that out! I was wondering about it and searching on the site. I found someone actually saying that the irreducibility of $f$ implies the irreducibility of $V(f)$. The counter example is enlightening.

Comment: No problem. I think the irreducibility of $f$ _does_ imply the irreducibility of $V(f)$ **if** the field is algebraically closed. Indeed, if $f$ is irreducible, then $f$ is prime (since we are in a UFD), so the ideal generated by $(f)$ is prime ideal. So $J=(f)$ is a prime ideal, in particular radical. Now applying Nullstellensatz, we get $I(V(f))=I(V(J))=\sqrt{J}=J$ is prime. But it is a theorem that $X$ is irreducible iff $I(X)$ is prime for affine algebraic set $X$ (See Proposition 3 in page 198 in Cox, Little, O'shea --- 2007 edition). In this case $X=V(f)$. Does this make sense? :)

Comment: @Prism: Yes, I understand that. So if we were talking about $\mathbb{C}^2$, we can show easily that $V$ is irreducible using that argument. But we cannot show it that way with $\mathbb{R}^2$. I actually figured out a simple way using another theorem in their book. :) I'll edit.

Comment: I just read your edit. Excellent! This is a very nice result.